# Thermodynamic 'Work Flow'; Based on relative or absolute pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, work

The thermodynamic work flow (energy) is defined as

$$W = \int PdV = \int PQdt$$

The units of $P$ are the same whether $P$ is considered relative (gauge) or absolute pressure. But then what should $P$ be, relative or absolute? Or can it be either, and does that just mean the basis (reference) of work is from vacuum to some finite pressure vs the difference between two non-zero pressures?

Comment: Gas pressure is always absolute. What is PQdt?

Comment: To get the work, and also, to apply the equation of state for a gas, you would have to use absolute pressure.

Comment: Work is done due to a displacement (or volume flow) against a pressure difference. So it shouldn't matter whether you consider gauge or absolute pressure, so long as you consistently use one of them.

Comment: @BobD - $Q$ is volumetric flow, $dV = Qdt$. An alternate  means of calculating work.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I absolutely (npi) agree for the state equation you need absolute pressure. But I believe work (energy) can be relative, as can pressure. Look at the physiology, medical, diving literature where work of breathing all uses *relative* pressure in the calculations. So I tend to agree with Deep's comment that it could be either. Just having difficulty imagining what it means using absolute (total) pressure.

Comment: @Deep , fully agree consistency important. But you will get very different numbers if you use relative vs absolute pressures in calculating the work of breathing in a medical ventilator or diving regulator as examples. So besides consistency there is a matter of *interpretation*. I can see it in for example the potential energy of an object at different heights, and the relative work moving the object from one height to another. The PdV loop in breathing can be looked at as differential work, but each half, inhalation, exhalation is relative to the chosen pressure 'zero' - which could be ...

Comment: @Deep ... either zero (atmosphere) or vacuum. Two very different numbers.

Comment: It depends on the particular force you are referring to.  If you are talking about the work done by the net of two opposing forces, then this involves a difference between the two forces, and the gauge contribution cancels out.  But, if you are talking about the work from each individual force, then the absolute pressure should be used.  For example, if you are talking about the force done by a gas on a piston, and your thermodynamic system is the gas, you should be using the absolute pressure, because this is what goes into the equation of state.

Comment: @docscience. Learn something new all the time. Looked it up. Says it's used in physics and engineering. Very confusing however to use Q (normally used for heat) to represent V. Thanks.